# jQuery: Add a class to an input when a value is already entered when the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, input, load

I'm using the follow jQuery code to style some inputs based on whether they are focused or if they have content in them.

```
$('.Textbox')
.focus(function() { $(this).addClass("selected") })
.blur(function() { if ($(this)[0].value == '') { $(this).removeClass("selected") } });
```

My problem is that some of my inputs are automatically filled in by the browser if the user is a returning visitor. Like username and password fields for example. Since the inputs have a value entered in them, I want to style them differently. Unfortunately the jQuery won't apply the styles until the user interacts with the input directly.

Is there any way that I can look to see if the input has a value (without the user interacting with the input) and then give it a class name?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried the `change` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it on "page load"

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.Textbox').each( function () {
        $this = $(this);
        if ( this.value != '' ) $this.addClass('yourClass');        
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Did exactly what I needed it to, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the `focus()` and `blur()` events are specific to user interaction. You should try the `change()` event in jQuery, as that gets fired when the value of an input changes, even if that change was triggered by a program and not just the user: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can see the applications, but unfortunately change() didn't help me on page load. Perhaps the browser auto-fills in the input fields too quickly for this event to trigger.